# MVC - when Create PDF report and try to Print, Arabic language coming non alphabetical

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, arabic

I'm using MVC. I wrote normal code to create my PDF report,
everything is OK except that sometimes when I print the report, Arabic letters are printed non-alphabetical as you see here:

[image: Example to my problem]

My code is:

```
LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ReportDataSource);

    string MimeType;
    string Encoding;
    string FileNameExtension;
    Warning[] Warnings;
    string[] Streams;
    byte[] RendereBytes;

    RendereBytes = LocalReport.Render(
        ReportType,
        null, //DeviceInfo,
        out MimeType,
        out Encoding,
        out FileNameExtension,
        out Streams,
        out Warnings
        );


    return File(RendereBytes, MimeType);
```

I already saved all my .rdlc report with Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - codepage 65001 but same problem come. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Rotativa PDF in MVC 
for help
http://www.dotnetstudy.com/rotativa-a-tool-for-pdf-generation-in-aspnet-mvc?id=31

Comment: Thanks but i want to use SQL server report (.rdlc ) to make grouping and so on ...